# flutter Hive calling method only once

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

im using Hive as my local storage to store data and i need to implement the following: i want to call a method inside initState() but only once...i mean that the first time when i open the application it will call the method..but everytime when i open the app again it won't call the method anymore

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    onlyCallingOnce();
  }

onlyCallingOnce(){
  Box box = Hive.box('progressSaving');
  box.put('perc_Special_1', 0.0);
  box.put('W1_D1_Special_1', false);
}
```

how to implement that ?

Comment: when u start an app. it runs all the programs written inside of it EveryTime. for ur cas,e u can just check if there is data in Hive or not, if not then put data. & It's really fast process